# Warlord Bravura Presence and multi-target attacks

Tags: dnd-4e, warlord

What are the rules for when the ally of a warlord with Bravura Presence uses their action point for a multi-roll or multi-target attack, e.g. Twin Strike or Winged Horde?

> When an ally who can see you spends an action point to take an extra action and uses the action to make an attack, the ally can choose to take advantage of this feature before the attack roll. If the ally chooses to do so and **the attack hits**, the ally can either make a basic attack or take a move action after the attack as a free action. If **the attack misses**, the ally grants combat advantage to all enemies until the end of his or her next turn. (*Martial Power* p. 103)

If I'm targeting three creatures with Winged Horde and I hit two of them, did the attack hit, miss, or both? Does it matter in which order I hit them?

Same question if I'm targeting the same creature twice with Twin Strike - one hit, one miss.
(The relevant phrasing here is **Attack:**[..], two attacks)

What if I'm using Synchronized Strike? (First a beast Attack with Effect: secondary attack; also, who would grant CA?)

And how does the feat Improved Bravura affect that?

> Benefit: When an ally uses your Bravura Presence, that ally gains either **a +1 bonus to the attack roll** or a +1 bonus to speed for the move action (the ally’s choice). (*Martial Power* p. 136)

Is that for all attack rolls in the aforementioned scenario's, or just the first one?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Thanks for taking the tour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The key here is the phrase "the attack roll".

> 1. Choose an attack power[. ...]
> 2. Choose targets. [...]
> 3. Make an attack roll[. ...]
> 4. Compare the attack roll's result to the target's defense. [...]
> 5. [...] An attack power's description describes what happens on a hit. [... S]ome specify an effect, such as half damage, on a miss.
> 6. If the attack power has more than one target, repeat steps 3 through 5 for each of them.
>
> -- "Making Attacks", *Rules Compendium* pp. 214-215

Making an attack can involve one or more attack rolls. This warlord class feature (and other presence features) don't specify "one of the attack rolls" or "each attack roll", so "the attack roll" has to refer to the step 3 concept in order to make sense.

That is, before you make **each attack roll** as part of resolving the power, you decide whether it's bravura or not, and if it is, you decide which benefit from the add-on feat you're taking. Any secondary attacks granted by hits or effects of the power also make attack rolls as part of resolving the attack, so make your bravura decisions for each of them. (Ranger beastmaster powers are a bit counter-intuitive in that the game fiction is that "the beast is attacking", but the ranger is the one making the attack roll with the beast's attack bonus. This means the ranger doesn't have to invest in a separate set of *+6 flaming tusk rings* for their boar to keep its attacks on parity, but it also means the ranger's the one making the bravura decisions and getting all the benefit and fallout.)

Once all your attack rolls have resolved, the attack is complete, and then you can take any free actions you got as a result of hits, keeping in mind the limitation on p. 194 of the *Rules Compendium* that you can only use a free action to make an attack once per turn. (Also keeping in mind that any movement that happens as a result is just regular movement, which provokes opportunity attacks as normal.)

One final note - while the Martial Power class features aren't called out in the errata, the warlord presence features in the original PHB were called out as not stacking - if you have multiple warlord allies with a particular presence class feature, you pick which one you benefit from, though different presences can still stack with each other. It's unlikely that you're likely to have a party with multiple bravura warlords, but if you do, you should probably only make one bravura decision per attack roll.